# Not all code in method is executed

Tags: c#, methods

I have a problem that I am trying to figure out.

In `Form1`, I try to run some method which is in `Form2`.

Example:

**Form 1:**

```
 `Form2.SomeMethod(name);`
```

**Form 2**

This is a method that I am calling from `Form1` and in this method I call other method which should do something.

```
public static void SomeMethod(string name)
{
     new Form2().method2(name);
}
```

And this is the method that doesn't work as it should

```
public void method2(string naziv)
{
     MessageBox.Show("test? "+naziv); //only for test. This works

     Button x = new Button();
     x.Margin = new Thickness(50, 20, 0, 0);
     x.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
     x.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
     x.MinHeight = 50;
     x.MinWidth = 100;
     x.MaxWidth = 150;
     x.FontSize = 20;
     x.Content = naziv;
     x.Name = "naziv";

     gridmiza.Children.Add(x);
     lbltest1.Content = "test? "+naziv; //only for test
     MessageBox.Show("test2?"); //only for test and this also works works
}
```

My problem is hiding between the two `MessageBox`es. First `MessageBox` executes and then the last one. But between these two `MessageBox`es nothing happens. Any idea what am I doing wrong?
I hope this question is reasonable because my English is bad and also I don't even understand my problem.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? It seems very unlikely that some code is skipped in the middle of a method. I would rather guess that the code is executed, but you cannot see the graphical results.

Comment: Button is added to a location not visible to you? I'm sure that a messagebox will pop-up, if you drop it in the middle between `x.MinWidth = 100;` and `x.MaxWidth = 150;`

Comment: And this is not advisavble:  `new Form2().method2(name);
`.  You do not need a new instance of a form to call the method.  This is a design that will not work out well.

Comment: See http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Yes i tried to debug. It goes through all lines of code. It is strange that my lable (lbltest) does not change his content as it should.

Comment: Debugging involves more than noticing that "it goes through all lines of code". You need to verify that they actually do what you expect them to do. In order to do that, you need to know and understand what it is that you expect. Typing random code, or modifying it in random ways rarely helps to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this line:

```
new Form2().method2(name);
```

You are creating a new `Form2` instance, calling the method, and then promptly discarding the instance, because you're not assigning it to anything. This is probably not what you meant to do. I'm guessing you either want to call the method on an existing instance, create a new instance and return it from the method.

I'm guessing you already have an instance of `Form2` created somewhere. You should call the method of that instance, either by passing in that instance, or by removing the `static` and use an instance member of `Form1`:

```
public static void SomeMethod(Form2 form, string name)
{
     form.method2(name);
}
```

Or:

```
public void SomeMethod(string name)
{
     form2.method2(name); // assuming Form1 has a member for Form2
}
```

Comment: Ok, this could be a part of my problem but i don't understand why (for example) my lbltest does not set his content to required value. Let's forget for buttons for know. I just try to make sure, that all code execute. Or I do not understand how it works

Comment: @Rok it does set the respective values, but you never get to see it, because you're discarding the form before it is displayed. You're probably looking at another instance of `Form2` that's not affected, because you're not calling the method on that object.

Answer (score 1):

As Rik point out, you discard the new form you created so nothing happens, at least you did'nt see it, if you try something like this:

```
using (var form2 = new Form2())
{
    form2.method2("aaa");
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

you can see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try following code, you are setting the MaxWidth/Height and MinWidth/Height, but not the actual height and with, so the button will not be visible.

```
public void method2(string naziv)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test? "+naziv); //only for test. This works
    Button x = new Button();
    x.Margin = new Thickness(50, 20, 0, 0);
    x.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    x.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    x.Height = 50;
    x.Width = 100;
    x.FontSize = 20;
    x.Content = naziv;
    x.Name = "naziv";
    gridmiza.Children.Add(x);
    lbltest1.Content = "test? "+naziv; //only for test
    MessageBox.Show("test2?"); //only for test and this also works works
}
```

And shouldn't:

```
new Form2().method2(name);
```

Not be:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.method2(name);
```